# How do I figure out the value of an unknown constant?

Tags: vb.net, enums, binary, type-conversion, lotusscript

How do I figure out the value of "$RichTextFormat"? This comes from Lotus 123 release 9.5 for Windows ClipboardFormat enumeration. I'm hoping you can give me a clue without knowing Lotus 123. I'm running Lotus 123 from VB.net and need to figure out the values for the Lotus123 enumeration so I can use them in my code.

> Syntax: object.CopyToClipboard [format]
>     Parameters: (Optional) Variant (ClipboardFormat enumeration). The format in which to copy to the Clipboard. The following table lists the allowed values for this parameter.
>
> $NativeFormat   Native format
>     $RichTextFormat Rich text format
>     ...

Here is my Lotus 123 script:

```
Print Typename ($RichTextFormat) 'output: LONG
Dim L As Long
L = $RichTextFormat
Print L 'output: 840
ThisDocument.Ranges("A:A1..A:B3").CopyToClipboard($RichTextFormat)
```

So in VB.net I assumed I could simply use 840 as the value for the constant.

```
myDocument.Ranges("A:A1..A:B3").CopyToClipboard(840)
```

Getting the error: "Value is out of bounds". By experimenting I found out that the equivalent is 257. The following works fine.

```
myDocument.Ranges("A:A1..A:B3").CopyToClipboard(257)
```

Why is this happening? I suspect there is some binary problem or type problem that I'm not thinking of. How do I figure out the value of these constants without trial and error? It must be that Lotus evaluates this enumeration differently than using a number. It must be using binary somehow.